# TS2322 - false | Element is not assignable to type ReactElement. Error does not consistently appear in app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I understand what the error is saying and I have been able to fix it, but I was hoping someone could provide some clarification on why it's happening now and why it isn't happening in other areas of my app, as well as why a function and a ternary with essentially the same type signature produce different results.

I wanted to display a basic error message in the following style:

```js
{!!error.message && (
  <Text>{error.message}</Text>
)}
```

But it gives the error mentioned in the title. I know `false` is handled by React and won't render anything, but knowing `null` is the preferred way of telling React not to render something I converted the above into a component. This makes the error go away:

```js
const Error = () => {
  if (!error.message) return null;
  return <Text>{error.message}</Text>;
}
```

Out of curiosity, I tried the same thing with a ternary which should have the same signature:

```js
{error.message ? <Text>{error.message}</Text> : null}
```

However this produces a very similar error to the one in the title, except it complain about null instead.

Knowing all 3 bits of code are valid React, and 2/3 being virtually identical, why is only one accepted by the TS compiler?

To further confuse things, I have the below in another part of my app and TS has no issue with it:

```js
{!loaded && (
  <RootStack.Screen name={SCREENS.SPLASH} component={Splash} />
)}
{loaded && !userAuth.authenticated && (
  <>
    <RootStack.Screen name={SCREENS.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
    <RootStack.Screen name={SCREENS.SIGN_IN} component={SignIn} />
  </>
)}
{loaded && userAuth.authenticated && (
  <RootStack.Screen name={SCREENS.TABS} component={Tabs} />
)}
```

Answer (score 28):

I also received this error using code similar to yours and similar to your observations, them being that the error can be avoided with [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and occurs when you use conditional logic with a `JSX.Element`.

I dug into the React documentation regarding the [conditional logic](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator):

> Inline If with Logical && Operator
>
> You may embed expressions in JSX by wrapping them in curly braces. This includes the JavaScript logical && operator. It can be handy for conditionally including an element...
>
> It works because in JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false`.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is `true`, the element right after `&&` will appear in the output. If it is `false`, React will ignore and skip it.

Which means that the following code is attempting to evaluate the `<text>` element with type `JSX.Element` as a `boolean`, so type error.

```
{!!error.message && (
  <Text>{error.message}</Text>
)}
```

In terms of a solution to proceed with `Inline && Operators` conditionals, the easiest appears to be wrapping your logic in a React fragment like so:

```
<>                {/*<-------- wrap in fragment */}
{!!error.message && (
  <Text>{error.message}</Text>
)}
</>               {/*<-------- close the fragment */}
```

---

Related Questions

- [Error with && logical operator jsx and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566207/error-with-logical-operator-jsx-and-typescript)
- [How to use ternary operator within the jsx of a react component along with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731875/how-to-use-ternary-operator-within-the-jsx-of-a-react-component-along-with-types)
- [Why is ternary operator in jsx not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551568/why-is-ternary-operator-in-jsx-not-working)

Comment: I have a similar setup, and if I wrap it with a JSX fragment, it results  for me "Type Element is not assignable to type 'undefined'"

Comment: Do you have a CodeSandbox to demonstrate the error? Let's explore and update the answer if there is a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found another option which worked for me in my case.

I had defined the parent component to what would have been the `<Error/>` with the following prop.

```
children: React.ReactElement<ErrorProps>
```

And so when the parent was receiving `false` as its `children`, it spit out the same error.

In order to get around that I changed my prop type to look like this:

```
children: false | React.ReactElement<ErrorProps>
```

My component was actually a bit more complex, so it took a little bit of inner conditional logic to handle a false value, but otherwise, it worked great, and I didn't have to sprinkle react fragments all over my code.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm too late , but if you define your return type as `JSX.Element | null` this problem wont occur.