# Error with && logical operator jsx and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm fair new to typescript and I was wondering why this fails

```
import {CircularProgress} from 'components/shared/material'

import React from 'react'

import loadingStyles from './styles'

const Loading = ({active}: {active: boolean}) => {
 const classes = loadingStyles({active, fadeSpeed: 1})
 return (
  active && (
   <div className={classes.overlay}>
    <CircularProgress />
   </div>
  )
 )
}

export default Loading
```

And when I try to use it in another component I get this message:

**Loading' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'false | Element' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.**

It is strange because that will work with regular js and here in typescript only works if I use a ternary statement like this one:

```
  return active ? (
   <div className={classes.overlay}>
    <CircularProgress />
   </div>
  ) : null
```

Comment: You *should* also use the ternary and return `null` if not rendering anything in "regular js" too. It's in the react docs.

Comment: You are trying to return a boolean value while what you actually want to achieve is return the jsx if active is true. I don't think first one will work with regular js either.

Comment: If you declare a function in TypeScript to return an `Element`, and within the function body return `false`, that won't compile, for the same reason.

Comment: But according to the docs, returning false is valid and it will be ignored, https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored , that is why it works using regular jsx

Comment: Those are examples of putting `false` as a child inside jsx. That's fine, and typescript will allow it too. Your code is an example of returning false from a component, with no surrounding jsx.

Comment: I think that's a fair point but honestly I think it would be awesome to support more falsey values, since null is a valid return already, and thinking that  they  won't be rendered, I don't see the why not it can be used like that.... but I think the comments here and the docs are clear enough, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to use a shorthand - you can do this. Use of <></> allows multi-line (optional in this case) and ensures the single element return on the function. And wrapping your conditional code around {} will ensure you can add any number of && checks within this to render your component.

```
  return (
    <>
      {active && (
        <div className={classes.overlay}>
          <CircularProgress />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Life saviour - thank you so much!